# Intel® Ethernet X520 10 Gigabit Dual Port -x/k Mezzanine Card

Tags: networking, dell, intel, 10gbethernet

what are the backplane connectivity options for this card?
though it is said for blades, we got this on a Dell PE C2100 rack...now there are two holes (ports) on servers backplane gazing at me...clueless what to do?

please advise

http://www.dell.com/us/en/enterprise/networking/nic-intel-ethernet-x520-kx4/pd.aspx?refid=nic-intel-ethernet-x520-kx4&cs=555&s=biz

Comment: Are you sure you've got the right product there? How do you know that that's the exact same card?

Comment: the card specs are printed on the bill of material/invoice

Comment: that doesn't always mean they're correct though, I'd definately be double checking, because a blade NIC has no place inside anywhere but a blade

Comment: I'm not going to open up one of our blades and check because I don't have any spares right now and I've got better things to do than cause myself a major outage today, but iirc the physical format of a mezzanine card means it physically wouldn't fit in a normal rack mount server. It _definitely_ would not expose any ports in the server's external ports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me see if I've got this straight: This part, which is certainly for blade servers, has been installed into a rack server.

Did Dell recommend this? If so, I'd be inclined to ask them how they think you should connect this. AFAIK this is indeed a blade part, so won't have a direct network interface of its own and is instead designed to add certain network connectivity options to a blade server via its backbone connector.

Comment: Correct, there's no physical interface on the mezzanine, as it lets the blade chassis decide which interface to connect to it.

Comment: oh is it? but this came thruough a Dell build. Thanks for the info

Comment: Are you sure it's the mezzanine card? Intel x510-10 comes in a number of models. 10Gbase-T, SFP+, SR etc. Most would fit in the C2100 but not the mezzanine card. What does the two ports look like?

Comment: this certainly not 10Gbase-T. The ports are looking like SFP, but empty without the modules.

Comment: In that case, John, it sounds like SFP+ copper/direct attached interfaces (http://bit.ly/mRot4Y for an example) which is what I'd expect, what we use where I work in fact, we have Dell servers too. You can either use those with a fibre transceiver, or with a copper "direct attach" cable. Possibly the Intel X520-DA2 card or a variant of that, I forget the exact Dell part number for it.